# Use default datepicker in Android

Tags: android, datepicker

Is there any chance to get the common DatePicker like in the most older examples

[image]

instead of this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are targetting API > 11, there is a method in DatePicker:

```
public void setCalendarViewShown (boolean shown)
```

while from yout xml layout:

```
 android:calendarViewShown="false"
```